# Bring a specific dialog to front when having multiple dialogs

Tags: android, android-dialog

In my application, I have multiple dialogs of various types, and I invoke them like `showDialog(dialogType)`.

I want a specific type of dialog to have a higher priority and to be shown always in the front. I even tried `higherPriorityDialog.hide()` to hide that dialog  and `higherPriorityDialog.show()` to again show it, so that it should come to front, but no luck.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I had to do something like this, keep a Vector of all the `Dialog' objects somewhere. Whenever a lowPriorityDialog comes, just finish highPriorityDialogs, and display that lowPriorityDialog and again display all the highPriorityDialogs. Hope I am not confusing you.

Answer (score -2):

most likely you have to close all other dialogs before you open another. so call .close() on one and call .show() on another

I am not sure if android supports opening of multiple dialogs at a same time even if they are hidden.

Comment: I've already shown multiple dialogs on top of one another. And all of them are shown and not hidden. When I say, multiple dialog types, I have a custom dialog i.e. `MyDialog extends Dialog` and android does support this.